# How to install node.js, nvm, npm on QNAP (NAS)

Tags: node.js, nas, qnap

in QNAP APP center has node.js 4.x and 0.8.X version

However, these two versions are too old, I hope we can install a newer version.

I try to login linux system installed through the command

https://www.ostechnix.com/install-node-js-linux/

nas seems to have removed some of the command, I checked it is `Ubuntu` but no `apt-get`, I can not install node.js through these comman

```
cat   /proc/version

Linux version 3.4.6 (root@BuildServer36) (gcc version 4.1.3 20070929 (prerelease) (Ubuntu 4.1.2-16ubuntu2)) #1 SMP Thu Oct 26 11:01:49 CST 2017
```

like this

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs npm
-sh: sudo: command not found

apt-get install nodejs npm
apt-get: command not found
```

I have not tried to install the mongodb should have a similar problem

My nas model is TS-439 Pro ii

Answer (score 1):

Or just go to qnapclub.eu a repository of “unofficial apps” - download it and install through the GUI in app center...

You have to select accept third party apps and you should be good to go..

Comment: Ironically, the only version available in the QnapClub repository is currently v6.9.1, while the official QNAP repository offers v8.9.4. The actual current versions are v10.16.3LTS and v.12.9.0...

Comment: On app center, there is 3 versions of node.js on QNAP all this 3 are bugged

node.js package V8.9.4.0.1 :
execute npm -v : give the error : Segmentation fault

V6.11.1.1.2 and version : V4.5.0.0.2
execute npm -v : give the error : Can't not find module npmlog

So i install manualy the package 14.1.0
npm -v : error while loading shared libraries: libatomic.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

I was straggling with the same issue on mine QNAP.

I found this tutorial: https://techblog.dorogin.com/running-nodejs-app-on-qnap-nas-via-pm2-3bdb838524e4 written by Sergei Dorogin.

Highly recommend you to install **pm2** which is production manager for node.js
https://github.com/Unitech/pm2

It took me around 3hours to set up everything, because I'm not good with Linux

Answer (score 0):

I haven't played with this yet, but it seems like using Container Station to install an official Node.js Docker image is the way to go. This gives you a complete preconfigured Linux environment to run Node in.